# How to use "rewire" module in my Angular 2 - cli, Karma, Jasmine unit test

Tags: unit-testing, karma-runner, angular-cli

I have a file which has few classes. One of them is exported and rest are internally used by it. All those 'used' classes are not exported.
I am trying to write a unit test for those non-exported classes and wanted to try 'rewire'module. However, when I try

```
var rewire = require("rewire")
```

my Karma, returns me an error

```
404: base/dist/rewire
```

How to handle that error?

Comment: you need to load `rewire` module in karma.conf.js like you did for rxjs or any other lib.